# ExceptionHandler не перехватывает исключения

Tags: java, kotlin, jwt, exception-handler

Итак, у меня есть исключение:

```
open class CustomException(open val code: String, override val message: String) : RuntimeException(message)
```

От него наследуются несколько других,

```
class DataAccessException(override val code: String, override val message: String) : CustomException(code, message)

class NoMatchingValueException(override val code: String, override val message: String) : CustomException(code, message)

class ApiException(override val code: String, override val message: String) : CustomException(code, message)

class JwtAuthenticationException(override val code: String, override val message: String) : CustomException(code, message)
```

которые и обрабатывает `ExceptionHandler`. Сейчас он выглядит так:

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = [DataAccessException::class])
fun handle(exception: DataAccessException): ResponseEntity<AbstractDto> =
        ResponseEntity.ok(AbstractDto(exception.code, exception.message))

@ExceptionHandler(value = [NoMatchingValueException::class])
fun handle(exception: NoMatchingValueException): ResponseEntity<AbstractDto> =
        ResponseEntity.ok(AbstractDto(exception.code, exception.message))

@ExceptionHandler(value = [ApiException::class])
fun handle(exception: ApiException): ResponseEntity<AbstractDto> =
        ResponseEntity.ok(AbstractDto(exception.code, exception.message))

@ExceptionHandler(value = [JwtAuthenticationException::class])
fun handle(exception: JwtAuthenticationException): ResponseEntity<AbstractDto> =
        ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .body(AbstractDto(StatusCode.UNAUTHORIZED.name, exception.message!!))
```

Все исключения благополучно перехватываются хэндлером и выплёвывают на фронт нужное соообщение. Все, кроме последнего: `JwtAuthenticationException`

Это исключение выбрасывается только в одном случае, при валидации JWM-токена.

```
    try {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getExpiration().after(new Date());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        throw new JwtAuthenticationException(StatusCode.UNAUTHORIZED.name(), "JWT token is invalid");
    } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
        throw new JwtAuthenticationException(StatusCode.UNAUTHORIZED.name(), "JWT token expired.");
    }
```

При этом, в консоль выпадает почему-то сразу три стектрейса:

```
JwtAuthenticationException: JWT token expired.
...
ERROR 22059 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception

JwtAuthenticationException: JWT token expired.
...
ERROR 22059 --- [nio-8081-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]

JwtAuthenticationException: JWT token expired.
```

При этом, на фронт вылетает просто надпись:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
```

Подскажите, что не так?

Comment: так а разве тут `@ExceptionHandler(value = [AuthenticationException::class])` не должно быть `@ExceptionHandler(value = [JwtAuthenticationException::class])`

Comment: Да, это опечатка, там именно что JwtAuthnticationException

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что ExceptionHandler перехваытвает исключения сгенерированные в контроллерах. А валидация токена производится до того как запрос поступил в контроллер.